# AWS secret manager time out sometimes

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, botocore

I am fetching a secret from secret manager on a lambda. The request fails sometimes. Which is totally strange, it is working fine and couple of hours later I check and I am getting time out.

```
def get_credentials(self):
    """Retrieve credentials from the Secrets Manager service."""

    boto_config = BotoConfig(connect_timeout=3, retries={"max_attempts": 3})
    secrets_client = self.boto_session.client(
        service_name="secretsmanager",
        region_name=self.boto_session.region_name,
        config=boto_config,
    )
    secret_value = secrets_client.get_secret_value(SecretId=self._secret_name)

    secret = secret_value["SecretString"]
```

I try to debug the lambda and later seems to be working again, without any change, those state changes happen in hours. Any hint why that could happen?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/botocore/endpoint.py", line 249, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/endpoint.py", line 321, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/httpsession.py", line 438, in send
    raise ConnectTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://secretsmanager.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

Comment: Is your Lambda function associated with a VPC? If so, is there any particular reason _why_ you associated it with a VPC? Also, is it associated with _multiple subnets_? It is possible that some of these subnets are Public Subnets and some are Private Subnets and it is randomly associating with a Public Subnet -- this will actually _not_ give Internet access to the function.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [legacy retry mode](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html#legacy-retry-mode) (is the default one in boto3), which has very limited functionality as it only works for a very limited number of errors.

You should try changing your retry strategy to something like [Standard retry mode](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html#standard-retry-mode) or [Adaptative](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html#adaptive-retry-mode). In that case your code would look like:

```py
from botocore.config import Config as BotoConfig
boto_config = BotoConfig(
    connect_timeout=3,
    retries={
        "max_attempts": 3,
        "mode":"standard"
    }
)
secrets_client = self.boto_session.client(
    service_name="secretsmanager",
    region_name=self.boto_session.region_name,
    config=boto_config,
)
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! I have literally been trying to solve this problem for months. It's so intermittent, which made it maddening to track down. Note: the `standard` retry mode uses a default of 3 `max_attempts`, so that line is redundant.